# Get all Listeners registered on a component

Tags: java, swing, events, awt, listener

I'm implementing a GUI with Swing, and I have a JPanel with some Listerners registerd on it:

```
JPanel graph=new JPanel();

graph.addMouseMotionListener(new java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        graphMouseDragged(evt);
    }
});
graph.addMouseWheelListener(new java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener() {
    public void mouseWheelMoved(java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent evt) {
        graphMouseWheelMoved(evt);
    }
});
graph.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        graphMousePressed(evt);
    }
});
```

This is just one example, the amount and the type of the listerners may change.

Now I would like to get all the registered Listeners on it in an array, so I tried:

```
java.util.EventListener listeners[] = graph.getListeners(java.util.EventListener.class);
```

From what I understand this method should return me all the listeners of the type `java.util.EventListener` registered on the object `graph`. This interface should not be the superinterface for any listeners?

So what I would expect is to get all the listeners of any type, but actually I get an empty array.

Am I going in the right way or am I missing something? Where am I wrong?

Comment: java.util.EventListener hasn't something with Listeners from AWT/Swing packages/APIs

Comment: @mKorbel According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html java.util.EventListener is a superinterface of MouseAdapter, MouseWheelListener, MouseMotionAdapter and also AWTEventListener

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) says "Returns an array of all the objects currently registered as FooListeners upon this Container." It does *not* say "Returns an array of all the objects that subclass FooListener that are registered upon this Container." If you look at the code, you'll see that it's implemented as a simple facade over the other various `getXListeners()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it doesn't work that way (although I understand why you think it would).

The `T[] Component.getListeners(Class<T> listenerType)` method only returns the listeners that has been added using the corresponding `addXxxListener(...)` method. I believe this method was implemented this way for convenience of the API designers/implementers, not for API users. I recommend using the `getXxxListeners()` rather than `getListeners(XxxListener.class)`.

Anyway, here's an example:

```
JComponent comp = new JPanel();
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter() { /* Custom impl */ }
comp.addMouseListener(ml);

// ml is returned
MouseListener[] mls = comp.getListeners(MouseListener.class);

// Nothing is returned, as there's no support for adding listeners 
// for generic EventListeners to a component
EventListener[] els = comp.getListeners(EventListener.class);
```

PS; If you are curious, it's probably easier to understand how this works, if you look at the source code. The important class is `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList`. :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping there was a way to avoid calling all the  methods individually

Comment: I agree, this is a bit of a problematic state of affairs.  If you look at EventListener in the API doc, it has about 60 subinterfaces (from "Action" to "WindowStateListener").  Not all of these will apply to all Components, of course, but I find it a bit mad that you potentially have to work your way through 60 different interfaces when they have a superinterface.

Answer (score 0):

I have used it a long time ago, this is how I remember doing it..

```
protected void eventChange(Change change) {
    for (ChangeListener listener:
         listenerList.getListeners(ChangeListener.class)) {
         listener.stateChanged(new ChangeEvent(this));
    }
}
```

And if you want to maintain your own collection of listeners, CopyOnWriteArrayList.